# Cannot update python version in ubuntu after installing it

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-20.04

I want to update python version from 3.6.1 to 3.7. What I did is installing python 3.7 and alternating the version for `python3` via `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`. It was found that there are multiple versions (I also installed version 3.8):

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).
Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   1         manual mode
```

(I am not sure why there isn't 3.6.1 on the list)

After alternating the version, when I type `python --version`, the terminal still shows version 3.6.1:

```
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

After several times of trying I am still not able to update my python version. It seems that it relates to Anaconda issue, but after searching the internet I still found no solution. What should I do?

I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using this command in your terminal would answer your question :D

```
which python
```

I am guessing you are under the environment of conda where python 3.6.1 is installed and its evident that you have already installed python 3.7 in your system environment (not anaconda env)

Try :

```
conda deactivate
python --version
```

Your system wide installation of python environment is totally different from your anaconda environment

if you want to upgrade from python 3.6.1 to python 3.7 inside anaconda use the follwing in when you are in an active conda environment for ex inside base:

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.7
```

Its better to make a new environment in conda by :

```
conda create --name ENVNAME python=3.7
```

If you don't want to use the anaconda environment by default remove it from your bashrc.